# Unknown identifier error and my strategy won't add to the chart because pine says it requires a output function

Tags: pine-script

So I am creating a trading system with pine script and I keep getting a undeclared identifier even though I have created the variables and then the second issue is that my strategy would not add to the chart because it says I need an output function but I have the strategy.entry function so I am confused , may someone take a look at my script please and tell me how to fix it?

```
  strategy(title ="My Long term strategy", overlay=true)

//DEFINITIONS
shortMa = ema(close,8)
longMa = ema(close, 14)
//MACD indicator
macdShort = input(12, minval=1, title ="MACD Fast length")
macdLong = input(26, minval=1, title = "MACD Slow Length")
macdSignal = input(9, minval=1, title = "MACD Signal Length")
mac= macd(close,macdShort, macdLong, macdSignal)
MACDLine= (macdShort - macdLong) 
//SignalLine= 9
//MACDHistogram: MACDLine - SignalLine

//Stochastic indicator
Length = input(14, minval = 1, title = "stochastic Length")
k= input(3,minval = 1, title= "stochastic%k")
d= input(3,minval = 1, title= "stochastic%d")
sto = stoch(close,highest(Length),lowest(Length), Length)
stoUppper = hline(80, title="Upper Limit",color=color.red, linestyle=hline.style_dotted)
stoLower = hline(20, title="Lower Limit", color=color.lime, linestyle=hline.style_dotted)

//VWAP indicator
v = vwap(hlc3)

// RSI indicator
src = close 
RSIlen = input(14, minval=1,title="RSI length")
EMAlen =input(10, minval=1 , title = "RSI EMA Length")
Up = rma(max(change(src),0), RSIlen)
Down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), RSIlen)
rsi= Down == 0 ? 100: Up == 0 ? 0:100 -(100/(1+Up/Down))
RSIEMA = ema(rsi,EMAlen)
band1 = hline(70, color=color.red, title = "Upper Line", linestyle=hline.style_solid)
band0 = hline(30, color=color.lime, title = "Lower Line", linestyle=hline.style_solid)
 
 //LOGIC
 longsignal = crossover(shortMa, longMa)
 macdlong = crossover(macdline, macdSignal)
 stolong = crossover(k and d, lowerlimit)
 vlong = crossover(close,v)
 RSIlong = crossover(rsi and RSIEMA, band0)
 
 //POSITIONS
strategy.entry(id = "longPosition", long=true, when=longsignal and macdlong and stolong and vlong and RSIlong)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script has structural problems:

1. It does not have a `//@version=4` compiler directive on the first line to tell the compiler which version of Pine you are using. See: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Versions.html
2. You have lines starting with a space. Code in the global scope must begin at column zero: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Structure_of_the_script.html
3. As the compiler error messages are telling you, you are referring to variables names which are undefined. Line 40, e.g., refers to `macdline` yet it's not defined prior to that reference. You have a `MACDLine` variable defined in line 12; if that's the one you want to use, spell it the same way. Pine distinguishes case in variable names.

You also have other problems. This for example:

```
stolong = crossover(k and d, lowerlimit)
```

As the refman for [`crossover()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_crossover) mentions, its arguments must be of type "float", yet you are trying to pass it `k and d`, which is a boolean expression itself based on two "float" variables, which doesn't make sense.

You have much work to do on the script and we can't do it all for you. This will give you a start with at least a well-formed script:

```
//@version=4
strategy(title ="My Long term strategy", overlay=true)

//DEFINITIONS
shortMa = ema(close,8)
longMa = ema(close, 14)
//MACD indicator
macdShort = input(12, minval=1, title ="MACD Fast length")
macdLong = input(26, minval=1, title = "MACD Slow Length")
macdSignal = input(9, minval=1, title = "MACD Signal Length")
mac= macd(close,macdShort, macdLong, macdSignal)
MACDLine= (macdShort - macdLong) 
//SignalLine= 9
//MACDHistogram: MACDLine - SignalLine

//Stochastic indicator
Length = input(14, minval = 1, title = "stochastic Length")
k= input(3,minval = 1, title= "stochastic%k")
d= input(3,minval = 1, title= "stochastic%d")
sto = stoch(close,highest(Length),lowest(Length), Length)
stoUppper = hline(80, title="Upper Limit",color=color.red, linestyle=hline.style_dotted)
stoLower = hline(20, title="Lower Limit", color=color.lime, linestyle=hline.style_dotted)

//VWAP indicator
v = vwap(hlc3)

// RSI indicator
src = close 
RSIlen = input(14, minval=1,title="RSI length")
EMAlen =input(10, minval=1 , title = "RSI EMA Length")
Up = rma(max(change(src),0), RSIlen)
Down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), RSIlen)
rsi= Down == 0 ? 100: Up == 0 ? 0:100 -(100/(1+Up/Down))
RSIEMA = ema(rsi,EMAlen)
band1 = hline(70, color=color.red, title = "Upper Line", linestyle=hline.style_solid)
band0 = hline(30, color=color.lime, title = "Lower Line", linestyle=hline.style_solid)

//LOGIC
longsignal = crossover(shortMa, longMa)
macdlong = crossover(macdline, macdSignal)
stolong = crossover(k and d, lowerlimit)
vlong = crossover(close,v)
RSIlong = crossover(rsi and RSIEMA, band0)
 
 //POSITIONS
strategy.entry(id = "longPosition", long=true, when=longsignal and macdlong and stolong and vlong and RSIlong)
```